# WPML injects a div on all ajax calls causing media upload problems

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wpml

### Problem

I am facing problem of selecting uploaded media since I installed **WPML 3.3.8** and activated it. I am using **WP 4.5.2 on apache 2.4/php 5.6.x**

#### So far

I have investigated this issue till I discovered that.
For some reasons WPML injects this:

```
<div id="lang_sel_click" onclick="wpml_language_selector_click.toggle(this);" class="lang_sel_click"><ul>
...</ul></div>
```

on all **ajax response**.
This means the ajax caller doesn't understand what's going on.

#### Speculations

I think there is a filter/hook of some sort which listen for ajax calls and response and there WPML injects it DIV.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML that you pasted looks like WPML's switcher. You can control where it gets displayed in WPML->Languages. There's no configuration option to add the language to AJAX calls.

I suggest to:

1. Check the locations in which you display the language switcher in WPML->Languages. Turn them off one by one and see if any of these stop what you're seeing.
2. Check that you haven't added a call to display the language switcher manually in your theme.
3. Try to disable other plugins or switch theme.